# Shortest path to N-1, N-1 of 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I try to solve a problem.. but I can't figure out why my algorithm assigns the array's cells with new arrays instead of integers..

[image]

**The input for the function is a string**

here is my try:

```
function pathFinder(maze){
  maze = maze.split('\n').map(value => [...value]);
  function pF(i, j, steps){
    if (i === maze.length || j === maze.length || i === -1 ||
      j === -1 || maze[i][j] === 'W') return;
    else if (maze[i][j] === '.' || steps < maze[i][j]){
      maze[i][j] = steps;
      pF(i, j+1, steps + 1); pF(i-1, j, steps + 1);
      pF(i+1, j, steps + 1); pF(i, j-1, steps + 1);
    }
    else return;
   }
  pF(0, 0, 0);
  if (maze[maze.length - 1, maze.length - 1] === '.') return false;
  return maze[maze.length - 1, maze.length - 1];
}
```

for some reason I can't understand, the cells are assigned with arrays each `maze[i][j] = steps` statement..

Comment: `return maze[maze.length - 1, maze.length - 1];` does not do what you think: it uses the comma operator. You need `return maze[maze.length - 1][maze.length - 1];`

Comment: @trincot lol thanks, problem solved..